# Add folder shortcut to launcher

Tags: 13.04, launcher, shortcuts

I have created a shortcut to /var/www folder in the name 'www' to my desktop.Is it possible to add/drag this folder shortcut to ubuntu launcher?

PLease help,
Thanks

Comment: Is that a symlink???

Comment: i have created the shortcut using ln -s /var/www www

Answer (score 0):

1. Install gnome-panel using command,

   sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
2. Create new gnome-desktop-item,

   sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new
3. Select type as location,

[image: 1]

4. Set name and copy & paste the folder location

[image: 2]

5. Select Icon Image(64x64-recommented)

[image]

6. Enter comment click ok

[image]

7. Now you can search and drag it into launchbar.